# Function not being called in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML context set up with a Q_PROPERTY to read, write and notify a combo box with an updated list of the COM ports. However, the function is simply not being called, I have qDebugs to specify whether the function is being called.

*.cpp

```
#include "input.h"
#include <QDebug>

void Input::setComPorts(QList<QString> comPortsList)
{
    if (comPortsList != ports)
    {
        ports = comPortsList;
        emit comPortsChanged();
    }
}

Input::Input()
{

}

void Input::updatePortList()
{
    qDebug() << "-------------";
    QList<QString> comPortsList;
    Q_FOREACH(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        comPortsList.push_back(port.portName());
        qDebug() << port.portName();
    }
    setComPorts(comPortsList);
}

QList<QString> Input::comPorts(){
    Q_FOREACH(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()) {
        ports.push_back(port.portName());
    }
    return ports;
}
```

*.h

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>

class Input : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QString> comPorts READ comPorts WRITE setComPorts NOTIFY comPortsChanged);
signals:
    void comPortsChanged();
public slots:
    void setComPorts(QList<QString>);
public:
    Input();
    void updatePortList();
private:
    QList<QString> comPorts();
    QList<QString> ports;
    QList<QString> updatePorts;
};

#endif // INPUT_H
```

*.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import Qt.labs.location 1.0
import Input 1.0

Page {

    visible: true
    height: Screen.height / 2
    width: Screen.width / 2
    Input {
        id: input
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: dropDown
        model: input.comPorts
        x:150
    }

    Button{
        id:refresh
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Refresh"
        onClicked :
        {
            console.log("test")
            input.updatePortList
        }

    }
}
```

The function not being called is input.updatePortList which is in the button.

Comment: TYPO:  change `input.updatePortList` to `input.updatePortList()`. Also use `QStringList` instead of `QList<QString>`. Also declare `updatePortList` as slots or Q_INVOKABLE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q_PROPERTY is irrelevant to this question. To call a function from QML, the function must be declared as Q_INVOKABLE.

```
class Input : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void updatePortList();
    ...
};
```

And you have to call it as a function from qml:

```
input.updatePortList()
```